# Why do some sites redirect to HTTPS but not others?

Tags: discussion, ssl, redirection

More specifically, `http://*meta.stackexchange.com/` redirects to `https://*meta.stackexchange.com`, but `http://*stackexchange.com/` does not redirect to `https://*stackexchange.com`. It is the same with the `stackoverflow.com` domain. Why is this the case?

Comment: In particular, you can refer to the checklist at the bottom of the above-linked post to see the status on various sites as this is rolled out.

Comment: @BradLarson Whoops! Didn't see that. :-/ Should I delete this question or allow it to be dupe-closed?